# Is my result for argument and absolute value correct

Tags: complex-numbers

I solved two exercises and hope that someone would check my work. Thank you in advance for your help.

Exercise 1: I calculated the length and arg of $(1+i)^{17}-(1-i)^{17}$:

First convert to polar coordinates $\sqrt{2}^{17}(e^{{17\over 4}\pi}-e^{-{17\over 4}\pi})$. Then it's clear that the absolute value is $\sqrt{2}^{17}$. The argument is equal to the argument of $(e^{{1\over 4}\pi}-e^{-{1\over 4}\pi})$ which is equal to ${\pi \over 2}$.

> Is this correct and is this the optimal way to do it?

Exercise 2: I calculated the argument of $i^{4711}$ (the length is clearly $1$). For this I use that the argument of $i$ is ${\pi \over 2}$. Then the argument of $i^{4711}$ is equal to the argument of $i^3$ which is equal to $-{\pi \over 2}$.

> Is this correct and is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't that $e^{17\pi/4}$ have an $i$ in the exponent? and why is it clear that the absolute value of that piece is $1$? Example 2 looks fine.

Comment: Your polar coordinates' exponents are lacking $\;i\;$ : $\;e^{\frac{17\pi}4i}\;$ and etc.

Comment: Anna, are you paying any attention to comments and answers? It's polite to engage with people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson After reading the answer I can now understand my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were already very close:

$$(1+i)^{17}-(1-i)^{17}=2^{17/2}\left(e^{\frac{17\pi}4i}-e^{-\frac{17\pi}4i}\right)=$$

$$\stackrel{\text{why?}}=2^{17/2}\cdot2i\,\text{Im}\,\left(e^{\frac{17\pi}4i}\right)=2^{19/2}i\sin\frac{17\pi}4=$$

$$=2^{19/2}i\frac1{\sqrt2}=2^9i=512\,i$$

Comment: Thank you I can see were I went wrong.